# MySQL - results from 'SELECT WHERE STH' and 'SELECT WHERE NOT STH' don't sum to full table

Tags: sql, mysql, select, where-clause

How is that possible that results from those 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `name` = 'Smith`
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE NOT `name` = 'Smith`
```

doesn't sum to whole table `workers`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `NULL` in `name` field does not get into either query.

In ternary logic which `SQL` uses, `NULL = 'Smith'` and `NOT NULL = 'Smith'` both evaluate to `NULL` and are filtered out.

Use `NULL`-safe comparison operator, `<=>`:

```
SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `name` <=> 'Smith`
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE NOT `name` <=> 'Smith`
```